# Exclude assigned articles from query

Tags: mysql

I have one query which prints all articles assigned to current article's category

```
SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid='$catid'
```

And in this table(below) there are articles which are assigned to current article as similar articles

```
assigned_id   fav_id
     1          45
     1          12
     1          53

SELECT fav_id FROM #__similar WHERE id='$id'
```

I want them to be hidden in first query, which is outputing all articles including one which are assigned as similar. So in this example articles with id 45,12,53 would be excluded

Comment: How are the tables related?

Comment: Don't use select *. Always select the minimum number of columns you need and preferably name them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full query:

```
SELECT distinct c1.* 
FROM #__content c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #__similar S on S.fav_id = c1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN c2 on c2.catid='$catid' and c2.id = S.assigned_id
WHERE c1.catid='$catid' and c2.id is null
```

As you can see, query joins __content with __similar thourh fav_id, that means, query is looking if this content is similar to som other content. In last join I chech that the similar item is in the same category.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    SELECT * FROM #__content c
     INNER JOIN #__similar s
    ON c.article_id != s.fav_id
    WHERE catid='$catid'
```